# The boolean equivalent of the post increment

Tags: javascript

In addition we have pre and post increments, `++x` and `x++`. So if you have a statement, the post increment will happen **after** the statement has been evaluated.

Is there something for booleans that will set a boolean to `false` (or `true`) after the statement is evaluated?

The reason I want it is to try to minimise the lines in a reduce statement.

I have an array `arr` of booleans where one (or more) of the entries may be true. If just one is `true`, I want the `reduce` to return `true`. **However** as I travel through the `reduce` I want to clean the array `arr`, so all entries are set to `false` by the time the `reduce` has completed.

This is my code, but I feel it can be done better:

```
let arr = [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false];
let result= arr.reduce((prev, v, i, arr) => {
    prev = prev || arr[i];
    arr[i] = false;
    return prev;
}, false);
```

This will return `true` and set all entries to `false`.

Edit: I was considering `fill` after using a `some`, which would have been similar to a suggested `map` in the answers below, but my array is quite big, where any `true`s are sparse. So I was not keen on iterating through the array twice. IE, I was not keen on:

```
let result = arr.some(v => v);
arr.fill(false);
```

Comment: No. The pre- and post-increment and decrement operators are for numeric values only. There are no equivalents for other types. This is a legacy of C from the 1970s, and depending on who you talk to, from the way that addressing modes worked on DEC minicomputers back then.

Comment: `const result = arr.some(e => e); for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = false;` if possible, i'd prefer not mutating, but using something like `map`, or just create a new array (`Array(arr.length).fill(false)`). If you want to codegolf, use the comma operator, but it will imho make things worse.

Comment: Why are you using reduce? You are not reducing the array. You are simply looping over it. What is the point of keeping track of the previous item if you are not using it?

Comment: I am reducing the array to a single `true` or `false`. I am using the `prev` in the reduce.

Comment: towards your edit: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: Do not use `reduce` for side effects. `let result = arr.some(v => v); arr.fill(false);` is so much simpler and easier to understand. It's probably even faster.

Comment: Or if you must do everything in a single loop, just write `let result = false; for (const [i, v] of arr.entries()) { result ||= v; arr[i] = false; }`

Comment: I think your comment about side effects in a `reduce` and your proposal of the `for` loop is my favourite answer @Bergi . It feels right for the large arrays I will be using where any `true`s are few and far between. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have your `reduce` return a tuple:

- 1<sup>st</sup> element is either true/false.
- 2<sup>nd</sup> element is an array of false.

You iterate only once and you don't mutate the original array.

```js
const xs =
  [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false];

const [ret, ys] =
  xs.reduce(([r, arr], x) =>
    (arr.push(false), [r || x, arr]), [false, []]);

console.log(`${String(xs)}`);
console.log(ret);
console.log(`${String(ys)}`);
```

Comment: Out of all the answers, this is my favourite. (Its given me ideas for other things I am doing.) But I just slightly prefer @Bergi 's last comment (the for loop) in my original post. But thanks customcommander.

Comment: I think @Bergi answer would mutate the original array but if you don't mind that it's a good answer to consider indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the operation and get at first the result and then map `false`.

```js
let arr = [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false],
    result = arr.some(Boolean);

arr = arr.map(b => false);

console.log(result);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. I was considering `fill` after using a `some`, which would have been similar to your `map`, but my array is quite big, where any `true`s are sparse. So I was not keen on iterating through the array twice. I have updated the question to explain further.

Comment: Doesn't this allocate a new array?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, yes, it does.

Comment: @Rewind, what do you mean with sparse?

Comment: sparse = there are very few of them. In a 5000 element array there may be about 4.